# Unable to generate new Token using adalService.acquireToken for Logged in user to consume Microsoft Graph API

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, access-token, adal

trying to generate new token using adalService.acquireToken() for accessing logged-in user details from Microsoft Graph API.
below written code is not generating a Token, Error: "error in acquiring token Token renewal operation failed due to timeout"
OR
"Invalid Token"

Here is What I have tried:

```
    onGetUserClick() {
    let hdrs = new Headers();
    hdrs.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.adalService.acquireToken);
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: hdrs });
    return this.http.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/", options);

}


    public get acquireToken() {
    var newToken;
    this.context.acquireToken('https://graph.microsoft.com', function (error, token) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("error in acquiring token", error);
            return newToken = null;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Acquired Token: ", token);
            return newToken = token;
        }
    });
    console.log("return called before token acquired");
    return newToken;
}
```

Ultimate goal is to get user Info using Microsoft Graph API.